# Repeat cell background color

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I have 6 base colors that go in order for each cell created in the following order: 
 
• yellow 
• dark yellow 
• red 
• dark red 
• lime 
• dark lime

I have an Array of those 6 colors in that order to use as background color of each cell but if I want to add a new cell and make it 7 cells I have to re-add the first color so the array looks like this: 
 
• yellow
• dark yellow 
• red 
• dark red 
• lime 
• dark lime 
• yellow

is there a way to make the six colors of the array repeat after the sixth cell is created?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are a lot of ways. Show you code. Then we will find the way which suites you code. If you don't have code, make some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use modulo:

```
NSArray *colors = @[ Red, Green, Blue ];

colors[0 % colors.count]; // Red
colors[1 % colors.count]; // Green
colors[2 % colors.count]; // Blue
colors[3 % colors.count]; // Red
colors[4 % colors.count]; // Green
// and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the `%` operator (modulus), something like this will do

```
UIColor *currentColor = colorsArray[row % colorsArray.count];
```

where `row` is the integer that represents the current row number, and `colorsArray` is your array of `UIColor`

You can read more about modulus operator here
http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/modulus.html

Comment: Thanks! this is the code I used to make it work:         
var currentColor:UIColor = Constants.cellColorsArray().objectAtIndex(indexPath.row % 6) as UIColor